# Compare() of two variables returns 'Equal' but identical() returns FALSE

Tags: r, testthat

Suppose you declared following function:

```
compound <- function(x,i,t) {
  x*(1+i)^t
}
```

What are the fundamentals of following results:

```
compare(compound(100, 0.1, 2),121) => 'Equal'
```

and

```
identical(compound(100, 0.1, 2),121) => FALSE
```

In the package testthat `expect_identical()` checks the second condition and returns a failure in that case, although the value is 121. What is a better alternative to verify the above function `compound()`?

Comment: Try `compound(100, 0.1, 2) - 121`. This is why `identical` retuns `FALSE`. `identical` also wants *everything* (say, the `names` attribute) else to be identical. The best alternative is `isTRUE(all.equal(compound(100, 0.1, 2), 121))`.

Comment: Thank you! I know how to proceed, but could you explain your *everything* further?

Comment: `identical` needs exact matches to return `TRUE`.I have given an example, a frequent `attributes`. But there are others. Try `identical(as.numeric(1:10), 1:10)`. The former is of class `"numeric"`, the latter of class `"integer"` and this is enough for `identical` to return `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rui Barradas. I have found another explaination which I guess could also be relevant for my topic. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Yes, I was about to close the question as a duplicate of that one. The error is so frequent it's a R FAQ many R users know by heart, FAQ 7.31.